# How do I sort values in Observable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I've got an Observable and Player has the following fields (among others):

```
enum Height, enum Status, enum Name
```

And I want to *return the Single best player* from this Observable (it's not empty): which has either `height = Height.Tall, status = Status.Open, name = Name.Short` (so if he's got a Height.Tall -> he's the best one and I don't care about other fields -> return this player. If no value emitted by Observable (== no Player) has Height.Tall -> let's compare status etc and return any player that has Status.Open).

I tried to write a comparator and then use a collect (this approach looks kinda hacky cause I have to provide a seed value), is there any other way to do this? (I was thinking about filter and mergeWith).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Observable is fetching players from somewhere over time (which is probably why you use an Observable in the first place). What you want to do is to keep track of the best player you've seen so far. That's what you do with a [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scan-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) or [`reduce`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#reduce-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) operator.

Let's say you've got an `Observable<Player> players` with `class Player(h: Height, s: Status, n: Name)`. Then you can do something like

```
players.scan((bestSeen, player) -> {
    // comparison logic, maybe in a 'Comperator',
    // returning the best one of 'bestSeen' and 'player'
})
```

If you use `scan`, it returns the best player seen for each comparison. If you use `reduce`, however, this will only emit an element when all players have been compared. (note: this only works on a finite `Observable`: the best player will only be emitted when `onCompleted` is called!)